# Parse Javascript SDK -- Save client-side `user` as server-side ` Parse.User.current()`

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I might be doing the wrong thing conceptually, so pls tell me if I'm wrong.

I'm signing in a user client-side using Parse's Facebook sign-on. I then am trying to post this `user object` to my server so I can have that user object server-side, but I can't find anything in the docs regarding this.

Do I have to simply pass the `user.objectId` and then re-fetch that user server-side? Or is there a way to actually pass this user and then set it as `Parse.User.current()` on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just had to get the auth'd `sessionToken` from the client-side login and post it server-side.

Here's the client-side Facebook login. `fblogin` is called when user clicks the login button. I've also left out the basic Parse/FB init:

function fblogin() {

```
    console.log("fblogin -- start");

    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
            success: function(user) {

                if (!user.existed()) {
                    postFBLogin(user);
                } else {

                    console.log("fblogin -- else -- user.sessionToken = " + user._sessionToken);
                    postFBLogin(user);
                }
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize. Error =" + error.message);
            }
    });
}


function postFBLogin(user) {

    console.log("postFBLogin -- start -- user = " + user);
    var sessionToken = user._sessionToken;

    // Post the login
    $.ajax({
      url: '/fblogin',
      type: 'post',
      // dataType: json,
      data: {sessionToken: sessionToken},
      success: function(data) {

          console.log("post error = " + data.errorCode + data.errorMessage);

          if (data.status === 200) {
               // window.location = '/home/language';
          }

          // If an error, show the prompt
          if (data.errorCode === 101) {
              $('#login-alert').show().text("Facebook login error.");
          }

      },
      error: function(error) {
           console.log("postFBLogin -- post error = " + data.errorCode + data.errorMessage);

      }

    });
}
```

And then server-side, I'm using `become()` of the `Parse.User` class to take that `sessionToken` and turn it into an auth'd user server-side:

```
exports.fblogin = function(req,res) {

    // var defaultLanguage = req.app.get('defaultLanguage');

    var sessionToken = req.body.sessionToken;

    Parse.User.become(sessionToken).then(function (user) {

      console.log("exports.fblogin -- become -- success");
      // The current user is now set to user.
      res.redirect('/home/language');

    }, function (error) {
      // The token could not be validated.
      console.log("exports.fblogin -- become -- error = " + error);

    });                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a Cloud Function, or a Before/AfterSave method fires, you have access to the user already:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('myFunction', function(request, response) {
  // the current user is in:  request.user
});
```

Comment: I'm not calling a cloud function right now. I signed on the user through the FB sdk, client-side, and I'm trying to access this user object server-side, but it's my own node.js server, not a Parse cloud server.