# Parse.com Express complete login process with Facebook

Tags: facebook, express, parse-platform

I am trying to tweak the Parse Express tutorial:

https://www.anyimg.org/ and https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anyimg

Basically, instead of starting with their default home page, I always show a login page if the user has not been logged in.  I was able to do that by adding a simple check for Parse.User.Current() at the Homepage endpoint and redirecting to login if they are not looged in.

For my next step, I want to allow Facebook login.  So I tweaked the login.ejs as follows:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
            appId      : '254642391362596',
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true
        });
    };

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fLogin() {

/*Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
    *//*success: function(user) {
        alert("login success with user " + JSON.stringify(user));
        if (!user.existed()) {
            alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
        //FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        //  alert("got fb me api=" + JSON.stringify(response));
        //});

    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
    }*//*
});*/

// log in with Parse
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(authData, {
    success: this._fbLoginSuccess,
    error: this._fbLoginError
});
}
</script>


<button class="btn-facebook btn-large" onclick="fLogin();"><img src="./images/FB-f-Logo__blue_58.png"> <span class="btn-facebook-text">Login with Facebook</span></button>
```

The good news:  When I try the commented block without the login block, I get a FaceBook login prompt, and I can go to the DataBrowser and see AuthData there.

However, if I use the //Login block, nothing seems to happen.

Also, if FB login is a success what do I change in app.js or user.js to allow the home page to render?  I have been searching docs and SO for a day now, and I don't see any clear docs on this.

Thanks for your help!

Note: I am rather new to both Parse and Express, but I have been able to make progress mostly on my own (please see my other postings here).

---

I have made progress.  The code above essentially works.  Remove unwanted alerts from above and use window.location.href = '"home"/one-of-my-routes".  However, I am still unable to send a post to my users.js page.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found this useful post. Albert, this has the become() that you suggested. And this helped me at least get one version working.

[Parse Javascript SDK -- Save client-side `user` as server-side ` Parse.User.current()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834870/parse-javascript-sdk-save-client-side-user-as-server-side-parse-user-curr)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is definitely possible (I've done it), but can't be achieved with the method you are using right now. Basically you can't access the `Parse.User.current()` in Express on the server if you do a login with Facebook JS SDK on the browser. It doesn't work. (See [this question](https://parse.com/questions/reading-express-side-parseusercurrent-from-client-side-facebook-auth) in Parse forums.)

The only way you can achieve what you want, as far as I know, is using the undocumented [parseFacebookUserSession middleware](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session).

**Edit:** Add step-by-step detailed instructions

To log in the user with Facebook on Express (server) you simply need to follow the steps detailed on the middleware's github repo. Start by adding the file [parse-facebook-user-session.js](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session/blob/master/parse-facebook-user-session.js) into the `cloud` folder. Then add the code shown on the readme to `app.js`, like this:

```
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
var parseFacebookUserSession = require('cloud/parse-facebook-user-session');

app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());  // Require user to be on HTTPS.
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body
app.use(express.cookieParser('123456789')); // YOUR_SIGNING_SECRET
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 3600000  } }));

var fbLogin = parseFacebookUserSession({
  clientId: 'FB_APP_ID',
  appSecret: 'FB_APP_SECRET',
  verbose: true,
  redirectUri: '/profile' // where the user will be redirected to after getting a token from Facebook
});   

// This route will require FB login. If the user is not logged in, it will be redirected to FB
app.get('/events/new', fbLogin, events.new);

// A route to log out
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Some notes:

- You must use HTTPS
- You must enable the 'Add Field' Class Level Permission for the `_User` class using the Data Browser
- You must enable 'Allow client class creation' in the app Settings (see the readme)
- A new class `ParseFacebookTokenRequest` will be created on the Data Browser. Disable all it's Class Level Permissions (again, see the readme)

**Important:** According to a Parse Engineer, it's possible to log in the user client side using the FB JS SDK. I haven't done this but it's somewhat explained in [this issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session/issues/7).

Comment: Thanks Albertis!  Wow, finally something definitive after a 6 month wait!  I am a JS/parse newbie, so it is not too much trouble could I request you to please post the comprehensive server code someplace and send me a link?  Also, what do you think of the "all server side option" proposed at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/parse$20facebook$20server$20side$20/parse-developers/KxxyZZScJFw/5dZKmlipFFwJ?  It is also not fully supported, so do you think the all-server option is the "lesser" of 2 evils?

Comment: @Cali Codr I've added all the steps (it's mostly a copy-paste from the middleware's readme). By the way, the Google Group link you added to the comment doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Albertis,  Thanks for posting the details.  Sorry about that link.  Here is the transcript:

Comment: 10/20/14
I am having a real hard time getting Facebook  login to work from the client side with Express.  Requests for help on this board and StackOverlow have gone unanswered.  I have noticed that others are also frustrated with the lack of response.  My project has now been stalled for 6 weeks, and I am sure that others have the same issue.

One thing that puzzles me is why Facebook login has to be on the client.  With Node and Express, the goal was to move everything to the server?  So I am assuming that FB login can be implemented as middleware.

Comment: Hector RamosParser  
10/21/14

Hi,

We currently don't manage this kind of authentication flow automatically for you, but it's something that we probably should do at some point. Until then, you can try using the following custom Cloud Module to add support for server-side Facebook Login to your Express app on Parse:

https://gist.github.com/hramos/63dd9ea0c05086a57a5c

Hope this helps,
Héctor Ramos

Comment: OK, I did a quick compare, and you are basically using the server side (undocumented https://gist.github.com/hramos/63dd9ea0c05086a57a5c) recommendation that Hector also posted at Parse.  Yes, I tried it and it works for me.  Not perfectly though.  I'll add some of the other steps that you mention, and that may close the gap for me.  I will also look into the client side link you posted.  At least I now have a couple of decent options (end to end) to explore , thanks to you.  Thanks Albertis!

Comment: The gist you refer to it's _almost_ the same as the middleware I pointed you to. It's done by the same guys from Parse. But the middlewre I proposed has some bug fixes (see [this pull request](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session/pull/6)). Hence, I would suggest using it instead of the gist. By the way, if you get the client-side login working (by getting the token from the server and using `Parse.User.become()`), share your code with us! Regards